# Re-compiling the old COBOL source codes with the latest compiler

Tags: cobol, zos

What are the possible issues which we may encounter while re-compiling old COBOL(V4) source codes with the latest compiler (COBOL V6). Can someone list out few of them?
Thanks.

Comment: There should be a migration guide provided with the compiler, isn't it?

Comment: Is there anything missing for you in Ka Lam's answer?

Answer (score 9):

Start with reading these 2 docs

In the migration guide, "Migration recommendations to Enterprise COBOL V5 and V6"
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_6.2.0/com.ibm.cobol62.ent.doc/migrate/igymch1600rec.html

Whitepaper "Migrating to the COBOL V5 and V6 compiler is different!"
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039560

Environment issues such as the use of PRELINKER (not supported in V5+); requirement of PDSE; V5+ executable are larger.

The typical COBOL programming issue is bad data processed by V4 COBOL compiler generated program used to be more tolerated; V6 compiler use newer instructions that don't tolerate bad data.  What is bad data? For example, a ZONE DECIMAL number that has invalid zone nibbles; a PACK DECIMAL number where the sign nibble is wrong.

Another area of issue comes from COBOL coding error that lay dormant for years, such as memory corruption, but when the memory layout of (not grouped) data item may not be the same as V4, the memory corruption cause program logic to change and expose the bug.

Comment: The COBOL V6+ compiler makes use of storage above the 2G bar, which is controlled by the MEMLIMIT JCL parameter.  The IBM default for MEMLIMIT is 2G.  However, very large programs may require more than 2G to compile.  Customers should make sure that their V6+ compile jobs always have at least 2G of MEMLIMIT available.

Comment: Check these:
- PARMLIB(SMFPRMxx) – Is the IBM MEMLIMIT default being overridden?
- IEFUSI exit – Is there a MEMLIMIT cap here?  If MEMLIMIT isn’t mentioned in IEFUSI, but REGION is capped there, then the MEMLIMIT cap is automatically set to the REGION cap, so MEMLIMIT code may need to be added.
- PARMLIMB(SMFLIMxx) – Is there a MEMLIMIT cap here?

Unless there is complicated code in IEFUSI, customers can normally override the MEMLIMIT cap by coding REGION=0M,MEMLIMIT=nG on their jobcard, where ‘n’ is the new amount in gig.  Note that REGION=0M is required to make the MEMLIMIT override.